# Object Index Blender 3.0

Tags: objects, cryptomatte

Unable to get Object Index output in Blender 3.0. I am using the process given in the image. Is it right? Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object's *Pass Index* is used with the ID mask, but to get the data you have to enable *Data* > *Indexes* > *Object Index* in the *View Layer Properties*. This will add an output to the *Render Layers* node called *IndexOB*.

To use the *Cryptomatte* feature, you don't need the *CryptoObject00* etc. outputs anymore, they are for the deprecated *Cryptomatte Legacy* node which will be removed in the future. In Blender 3.0 and above the method is as follows (from the *Blender Manual*):

1. Enable Cryptomatte Object render pass in the Passes panel, and render.
2. In the compositing nodes, create a Cryptomatte node and select the Cryptomatte layer.
3. Attach a Viewer node to the combined pass of the render layers.
4. Use the Cryptomatte Add/Remove button to sample objects from the Compositor backdrop.
5. Use the Matte output of the Cryptomatte node to get the alpha mask.

Here's an illustration of what to do in the *Compositor*:

[image: enabling cryptomatte]

[image: picking an object]

[image: cryptomatte outputs]

[image: picking from image]

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. That helped me a lot. But need a little more help. I couldn't find Object Index in view layer properties (only Combined, Z, Mist, Normal are there). Can it be found somewhere else?

Comment: Ohh.... Got it... It's there. I was in Eevee. When I switched to Cycles, I found it. Thank you, thank you so much for all your effort.

Comment: Yes, it's in _Cycles_, sorry for not making it clear. Didn't know you were in _Eevee_ and since I almost never use it, I just supposed you were in _Cycles_.

Comment: @TapasRoy Would you consider accepting the answer then if it was helpful? 

Comment: Yes absolutely....It was really helpful

Comment: @TapasRoy I meant what is described here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Yes.... did it.